# gnuplot plotting file with error bars containg strings and number in a colum as xtics

Tags: linux, gnuplot

In Linux/Ubuntu i have plotted a file with 3 columns ,x, y and error bars. Now i have file with numbers and text in first column. i can i plot it with error bars with numbers and string in the label?.
The contents of file "file1.dat" are

```
` std 0.05 0.005 
  0.1 0.02 0.003
  0.2 0.01 0.001
 `
```

I have tried this
`plot "file.dat" using 2:3:xtic(1) w yerrorbars` but i get error on this

Comment: How can i plot it with error bars with numbers and string in the label?.

Comment: Your data does not seem correct. What does each column represent?

Comment: The first column has 'Std'  representing Standard version of protocol and second and third row of first column represent same protocol with a parameter x set to value of 0.2 and 0.3  respectively in the protocol, so mean and standard deviation of elements in first column are shown in second and third columns